# Spring web flow configuration with JSF getting Exception

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-webflow

Spring web flow configuration with JSF getting Execption

```
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment.merge(Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;)V
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.setParent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:392)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

when i have configure all things for flow but i am getting this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to conflicting versions of Spring on your classpath.  #merge was introduced in Spring Framework 3.1.2: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html#merge(org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment)

I would guess that you have a spring-context 3.1.2 jar and a spring-core 3.1.0 or 3.1.1 jar trying to interact with each other here, and obviously failing.

Comment: so which version i should use for all

Comment: Thanks Chris i have finished.